# effect of position of fileds in a class?

Tags: java, class, compiler-construction, constructor, compiler-optimization

Is there any difference in the code generated for the following classes in java:

```
class A_noConstructor
{
    public static int par1;
    public static int par2;

    void method1(){
    }
    void method2(){
    }

}

class A_wConstructor 
{
    public static int par1;
    public static int par2;

    public A_wConstructor(){
    }

    void method1(){
    }

    void method2(){
    }

}

class B_noConstructor 
{
    void method1(){
    }
    void method2(){
    }

    public static int par1;
    public static int par2;

}


class C_noConstructor 
{
    public static int par1;
    void method1(){
    }
    public static int par2;
    void method2(){
    }

}
```

If I replace say class A_noConstructor directly by B_noConstructor or C_noConstructor, will par1 and par2 have the same memory address in all the cases ? As the compiler will parse the source in different manner for these classes, will there be any difference in the symbol table generated by the compiler for these classes?

EDIT: void A_wConstructor() changed to public A_wConstructor();

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: This is not a constructor, this is a void method: `void A_wConstructor(){}`, in `class A_wConstructor`.

Comment: There is no such thing as memory address in Java. The compiler is free to use any memory address as long as the results adhere to Java specification.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends very much on the compiler.  There can be a lot of ways to represent the same source code in machine code, and then compilers can have e.g. optimisation options that make a difference too.  So just because the code generated may be the same in a particular case, you can't rely on that always being true.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in class that you create with (only constructor with no arguments) or without constructor. anyway the compiler 'll create one constructor for you **SYNTHESIZED DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR**.

But the order might make some difference (but its not explicit; no difference for us)
the symbol table 'll be updated (add literals, variables,...) in order of parsing.

The order alone 'll be different and memory address may change but its associated with table entries. so its useful for calling the function alone. i think it won't cause any performance issue or difference.